# Developer Account Access in Google Play Store account to access API Access section

Tags: google-play-console, react-native-iap

I want to use Google Play Console API but for that need developer account owner's permission, I already got those permissions from owner but still getting this page, can anyone tell me if I'm missing anything ?

[image]